# How to configure PHP 7 - Apache with MySQL PDO driver in Debian Docker image?

Tags: mysql, apache, pdo, docker, php-7

I'm using official docker images for PHP 7 (7.0.3-Apache) and MySql (5.7.10).
Using docker-compose, created containers from images and linked both.

Copied php.ini from https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.3/php.ini-production, replaced *dll* extensions with *so* and placed that file in */usr/local/etc/php* and enabled _pdo_mysql_ extension in it.
`extension=php_pdo_mysql.so`

*phpinfo* shows *php.ini* loaded but not *pdo_mysql* extension because it's not installed.

I googled and tried different extension names with `apt-get install`:
`php-mysql`, `php7-mysql`, `php7.0-mysql`, `php7.0.3-mysql`.

None of them works. Error says: `E: Unable to locate package`.

With `php5-mysql`, it's get installed but after restarting apache with command: `docker kill --signal="USR1" <container-name>`, extension doesn't show loaded in *php.ini*.

(Don't think it's much related to docker but I'm new to docker and trying with that now, so mentioning it here.)

Can anyone help to configure *pdo_mysql* extension with *php7-Apache*?

Comment: Install them using pecl instead

Comment: Not working with pecl, may be because of _php 7_:
`compilation terminated.
Makefile:195: recipe for target 'pdo_mysql.lo' failed
make: *** [pdo_mysql.lo] Error 1
ERROR: 'make' failed`

Comment: Found `docker-php-ext-install` command, which may be useful but it seems that may be used at the time of building docker image with `RUN` command because `apt-get install docker-php-ext-install` doesn't work.
I'll try with that.

Comment: Using `docker-php-ext-install` at the time of building image threw some errors but still it worked!

Answer (score 6):

You need the Dotdeb repository in /etc/apt/sources.list on your docker image:

```
FROM php:7-apache

# Install pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update \
  && echo 'deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo 'deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg \
  && apt-key add dotdeb.gpg \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y php7.0-mysql \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```